# Email Template font size

Tags: community, email, email-template, html, apex-email-service

Hi below is my mail markup HTML , is there any way i can make font size it to 10-12

```
<p>ASDFFGHHHH</p>
<p>EDFGFTRFG.</p>
<p>FGBCVHFBV
</p>
<p>gsdfsdjfksdf.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always use a CSS font-size property like this 
`<p style="font-size:30px">ASDFFGHHHH</p>` to change the font size